# Insert values in both related tables MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql

I have two tables:

```
create table `db_csms`.`tbl_item_requester`
(
    `id` int not null,
    `item_id` int not null,
    `requester_id` int not null,
    foreign key(`item_id`) references `db_csms`.`tbl_items`(`item_id`),
    foreign key(`requester_id`) references `db_csms`.`tbl_user_details`(`user_id`),
    primary key (`id`)
);
create table `db_csms`.`tbl_item_requests`
(
    `id` int not null,
    `item_requester_id` int not null,
    `quantity` int(5) not null default 0,
    foreign key(`item_requester_id`) references `db_csms`.`tbl_item_requester`(`id`),
    primary key (`id`)
);
```

`tbl_items` and `tbl_user_details` are already populated with values. My problem is when a new row is added into table 1 because the table 2 uses the id of that new row inserted in table 1.

My issues are:

1. How to get the newly inserted row id of `table 1` which is needed for inserting in `table 2`.

Strategy to solve this issue(my thinking):

1. Remove auto_increment and then generate a random value (using C# code) and use that value in both tables.

Are there any workaround to this problem? Do i have to change my strategy? Is the Database design incorrect?

Comment: Use `last_insert_id()`:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id.

Comment: @GordonLinoff does that return the correct id for multiple inserts from different clients

Comment: You have C# as a tag. How are you inserting records? SqlCommand? Linq-to-Sql? EF? Please show your c# code. ORMs provide the auto-generated id automatically.

Comment: Your question is specifically in the singular:  "How to get the newly inserted row id".  However, if you have multiple ids inserted in a single statement, they should be consecutive.

Comment: @Delphi.Boy `MySqlCommand`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using MySQL as your database, there is the specific function `LAST_INSERT_ID()`
which only works on the current connection that did the insert.

Answer (score 1):

In case of SQL Server you could write:

```
Insert .... Values(....); Select Scope_Identity()
```

and use `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()` that returns the first value of the first row, which would be the ID of newly inserted row. In MySql, you should be able to write `last_insert_id()` instead of `Scope_identity()`.